# Sms delivery application

Tags: android, sms

I'm tired trying to find sms delivery applications at play market. The following list contains requirements which application should satisfy:

- Send sms to multiple recipients, not mms
- Manage list of recipients, i.e. I need to be able to add new recipients to "chat" or remove some of them
- Show delivery status for group distribution: 20 sent, 2 failures, 1 in progress

Interested in both free/paid apps.

Comment: While waiting for matching recommendations, be welcome to check my list of apps for [Short Messages](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_shortmessage).

Comment: I'm not sure that my suggestion will work exactly for your need but you can try it. You can use  [Bulk SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buffersms&hl=en) to send sms to multiple recipients,manage list. To get delivery status use [Delivery Reports](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.droida.deliveryreports&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Twilio.com](http://www.twilio.com)?  Their API looks like a real breeze to use for what you're after!

Comment: In my country (Kyrgyzstan) I can choose plan with $0.0029 per message, but twilio offers $0.04 per message. (13.8 times more expensive)

Comment: Yikes!  I wonder why that is?

Comment: You may open pricing page of twilio and choose a country and check exact prices for that country. Twilio offers low prices for many countries but not for third world ones :) Local messaging platform here offers $0.018 per message. That's not perfect too. But from phone or gsm modem i can use special cellphone plan with $0.0029 per message. If i will not find anything good for android, seems I wiill have to write some app for linux which uses gsm modem ))